# How to stop useSelector from firing when object is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm making a simple web app that has nested objects and I noticed when I delete the members object, which contains the sections object, I get an error because useSelectors is looking for the members.

My question is how do I make a dynamic useSelector that will stop firing when the object it is looking for or the object it is nested in is empty or the object is deleted.

```
    const selectedTool = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.selectedTool)
    const i = parseFloat(selectedTool)
    const members = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.sheets[i].members)
    const selectedMember = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.selectedMember)
    const sections = useSelector(state => state.dashboard.sheets[i].members[selectedMember].sections)
```

This is what the members object looks like as well as the nested sections object.

```
members: {
          0: {
              memberId: '',
              materialId: '',
              sectionId: '',
              totalLengthOfMember: '',
              yAxisUnbracedLength: '',
              yAxisEffectiveLengthFactor: '',
              zAxisUnbracedLength: '',
              zAxisEffectiveLengthFactor: '',
              unbracedLengthLateralTorsional: '',
              lateralTorsionalModificationFactor: '',
              slendernessRatioInCompression: '',
              slendernessRatioInTension: '',
              sections: {
                  0: {
                      sectionId: '',
                      sectionShape: '',
                      sectionName: '',
                      sectionView: '',
                      sectionEdit: ''
                  }
              }
          }
        },
```

My goal is to allow the user to delete the members object. However when the user does that, the sections useSelector gives an error because it cannot find a member index.

How do I fix this? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy, don't render the component that uses that selector if there are no members.

Your reply will most likely be, "but all those `useSelector`'s are in the same component"

to which I will answer:

Your component is too large, just make smaller, single responsibility ones and split the `useSelector`'s amongst those.

Post your component code.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping a newbie like me sir! More power to you!